# Detect Swipe gesture from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am loading local HTML file in IFrame using HTML/Javascript in windows store development(Windows 8). I am trying get Swipe event from Iframe.

I tried with this [sample](http://sdrv.ms/18fGkhp) & [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968035.aspx). I fallowed the Mouse wheel scenario which contains one div element.
For Iframe it doesn't work.

My code:

```
<body>
    <iframe  id="iframe_Id" src="split.html" style="height:768px; width:1366px;" onload="Load();"></iframe>
</body>
```

```
function Load() {

var elt = document.getElementById("iframe_Id");

    elt.style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
    var gobj = new MSGesture();
    // Defining gesture object for Pen, mouse and touch
    gobj.target = elt;
    elt.gesture = gobj;
    elt.gesture.pointerType = null;

    // Creating event listeners for gesture elements
    elt.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", onPointerDown, false);
    elt.addEventListener("MSGestureTap", onTap, false);
    elt.addEventListener("MSGestureHold", onHold, false);
    elt.addEventListener("MSGestureChange", onGestureChange, false);

    // Mouse Wheel does not generate onPointerUp
    elt.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd", onGestureEnd, false);

}

function onPointerDown(e) { 
 var content = document.getElementById("iframe_Id");
}
```

I created functions for all the events. But when swipe in my IFrame the event not raised.
 I structured here. I need to work with Swipe.  Please help me to out from this.

Answer (score 5):

If split.html is a local file, you should listen for the events from within the `iframe`. You can then use `parent.postMessage()` to communicate up to the host/parent HTML page.

Alternatively, you can investigate the [new WebView control](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/10/01/blending-apps-and-sites-with-the-html-x-ms-webview.aspx) available to HTML/JavaScript apps in Windows 8.1.

Comment: First I apologize for very late reply. I am trying to listen events from Iframe only. But I am unaware about `Parent.postMessage()`. I am new to Javascript.
Can you share any source link which have brief description which is relevant to my case. Thanks

Comment: & I want to clarify one more thing is `still The webview has limitation like Disable ZOOM`.
SO it is not applicable for my case

Comment: Right now I am working for "listen for the events from IFrame".
I will get back to U after try.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your `<iframe>` inside a `<div>` block, like this :

```
<body>
   <div id="watch">
       <iframe id="iframe_Id" src="split.html" style="height:768px;
       width:1366px;" onload="Load();">
       </iframe>
   </div>
</body>
```

And then you look the swipe in the `div#watch` instead of the `iframe`, because the touch event will be in the DOM and not in the iframe.

Comment: Is this really necessary? Why looking for the swipe in a new div instead of the body?

Comment: @Natuu 
I did what U suggest. It is not working. I am able to get swipe on div.. But not Iframe